# How to turn off autocommit in mariadb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mysql-workbench, mariadb, mariasql

I am using mariasql and the mysql workbench IDE for mariasql, but I am not able to disable the autocommit mode.  How do I turn off the autocommit?

Answer (score 1):

In the SQL editor there is a toolbar button that allows to toggle auto commit mode:

[image]

Switching off auto commit will enable the 2 other blue buttons that can be used to start and commit a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I use XAMPP-VM with MariaDB with InnoDB. Couldn't manage to disable [autocommit](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#autocommit) with my.conf, however, I edited mysql.server file (for XAMPP-VM it's in /opt/lampp/bin folder) and added this parameter to startup

```
--autocommit=0
```

So at the end, it looks like this

```
...
case "$mode" in
  'start')
    # Start daemon
    ...
      $bindir/mysqld_safe --autocommit=0 --datadir="$datadir" --pid-file="$mysqld_pid_file_path" "$@" &
    ...
```

and it did the trick. You can check it with this after stop-start (restart won't apply the change as that goes on a different path in the switch)

```
select *
from information_schema.global_variables
where variable_name = 'AUTOCOMMIT';
```

The other side of the coin is if you upgrade then you need to repeat this.

Hope, you can adopt this solution / gives you some idea how to do it!

Answer (score 0):

You can set autocommit to false for the session :

```
SET autocommit = 0;
```

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/server-system-variables/#autocommit

Comment: After applying SET autocommit=0  whenever i am trying to insert data using Node.js its inserting the data to the database. and also its showing the data in mysql Workbench.

Comment: Test using START TRANSACTION instead. After inserting results do a COMMIT or a ROLLBACK.

Comment: Is there any command to do autocommit off so that it will affect both mariasql and mysql workbench

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found is to add `--autocommit=0` to the startup command of the daemon.

**Environment:**

```
$ mariadb --version
mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.6-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

$ grep PRETTY_NAME /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 7.9"
```

**One-line command:**

*NOTE: You still need to add `--autocommit=0` manually.*

```
$ vim /usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service && systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart mariadb && mariadb -u root -e "show variables like '%autocommit%'"
```

**Step-by-step commands:**

1. Open the job file with a text editor

```
$ vim /usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service
```

2. Add `--autocommit=0` to `ExecStart` (for me it was in #92)

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mariadbd --autocommit=0 $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION
```

3. Reload the daemon

```
$ systemctl daemon-reload
```

4. Restart the service

```
$ systemctl restart mariadb
```

5. Check the status of `autocommit` variable

```
$ mariadb -u root -e "show variables like '%autocommit%'"
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| autocommit             | OFF   |
...
+------------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score -1):

I consider it a mistake to turn off `autocommit`.

There are 3 ways for dealing with autocommit:

- `autocommit=1` -- all statements are immediately committed.  This is usually fine for casual usage.
- `BEGIN` ... `COMMIT` -- where you explicitly bracket a set of SQL statements.  By having the `BEGIN`, you are reminded that a `COMMIT` will be needed.
- `autocommit=0` ... `COMMIT` -- I see this as error prone.  You default autocommit to 0, but then forget to issue `COMMIT`.  Then you wonder why your `INSERTs` disappeared.